# Populationg the Fact table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dimensional-modeling

I am new to dimensional modelling as is kind of stuck. The scenario is that the 'Company' has outsourced the filling of its holiday cover and sickness cover to an agency which they fill and each filled session is called a shift.I have a 4 dimension tables as below.For simplicity I have only included one row each.I am using sql developer.

**Company dimension**- contains all the details of the branches of the company

```
BranchId|BranchName|Postcode|County
12      |Kensington|rt5gg   |newengland
```

**Shift_worker dimension**- contains all details of the shift worker who filled covered

```
worker_id|worker_name|phone
33       |Steve Smith|07766755543
```

**Shift_request dimension**- contains all details of the requests made by the company to the agency

```
Request_id|Branch_id
1221      |12
```

**Time_dimension**

```
time_id|week_num|day_of_the_week|quarter_num|weekend_flag|Year
221    |3       | 3             |2          |N           |2014
```

Finally the **shift table** from which the fact table will read

```
shift_date |shift_status|shift_id|request_id|worked_hours|type
------------------------------------------------------------------
 09-01-2011|Filled      |8899    |1221      | 2          |cleaner  
21-01-2011 |Cancelled   |6677    |1332      | 0          |Admin_assistant
```

I have created a fact table as below

```
CREATE TABLE "FACT_company" 
   (    "FACT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "TIME_ID" NUMBER, 
    "BRANCH_ID" NUMBER, 
    "WORKER_ID" NUMBER, 
    "REQUEST_ID" NUMBER, 
    "SHIFT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "WORKED_HOURS" NUMBER, 
    "TYPE" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "SHIFT_STATUS" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "COMPANY" ;
```

How can i populate this fact using a cursor in PL/SQL? My aim is to analyze the data afterwards to find how many shifts were cancelled each month, how many were filled each quarter, etc. I hope i am in the right path.

Comment: You don't appear to have anything which links a Worker to a Shift.

Answer (score 2):

I've added two columns to `shift_table` as `WorkerId int` and `timeId int` and populated them with appropriate values in the following strategy :

```
SQL> create table Company_dimension( BranchId int, BranchName varchar2(50), Postcode varchar2(15), County varchar2(50));
SQL> insert into Company_dimension values(12,'Kensington','rt5gg','newengland');

SQL> create table Shift_worker_dimension( worker_id int, worker_name varchar2(50) , phone varchar2(15) );
SQL> insert into Shift_worker_dimension values(33,'Steve Smith','07766755543');

SQL> create table Shift_request_dimension( Request_id int, Branch_id int);
SQL> insert into Shift_request_dimension values(1221,12);

SQL> create table Time_dimension( time_id int, week_num int, day_of_the_week int, quarter_num int, weekend_flag varchar2(1),Year int );
SQL> insert into Time_dimension values(221,3,3,2,'N',2014);

SQL> create table Shift_table( shift_date date, shift_status varchar2(25), shift_id int, request_id int, worked_hours int, type varchar2(25), WorkerId int, timeId int );
SQL> insert into shift_table values(to_date('09-01-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),'Filled',8899,1221,2,'cleaner',33,221);  
SQL> insert into shift_table values(to_date('21-01-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),'Cancelled',6677,1332,0,'Admin_assistant',null);

SQL> create table fact_company(FACT_ID NUMBER, TIME_ID NUMBER, BRANCH_ID NUMBER, WORKER_ID NUMBER, REQUEST_ID NUMBER, SHIFT_ID NUMBER, WORKED_HOURS NUMBER, TYPE VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), SHIFT_STATUS VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) );

SQL> create sequence seq_fact start with 1;

SQL> insert into fact_company
select seq_fact.nextval,
       td.time_id, 
       cd.branchid, 
       sw.worker_id, 
       sr.request_id, st.shift_id, st.worked_hours, st.type, st.shift_status
  from Shift_table st 
  join Shift_request_dimension sr on (sr.request_id = st.request_id)  
  join Company_dimension cd on ( sr.branch_id = cd.branchid )
  join Shift_worker_dimension sw on (sw.worker_id = st.workerid)
  join Time_dimension td on (td.time_id = st.timeid);

SQL> commit;
```

Comment: @dwalker thany you too.